# AngularJS - Filtering with multiple changing parameters in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just trying to figure out how to go about doing this. The basic idea of what I am trying to achieve is this

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: myFilter">

$scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
    return item === 'red' || item === 'blue'; 
};
```

However in my case, my filter parameters are stored in an array that will be changing dynamically based on user input. I have tried this but it won't work as I am returning in the loop.

```
var index;
$scope.filterParams = ['red', 'blue']

$scope.myFilter = function (item) {
    for (index = 0; index < $scope.filterParams.length; ++index) {
        return item === $scope.filterParams[index];
    }
};
```

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
app.filter('myFilter ', function() {
   $scope.filterParams = ['red', 'blue'];

   return function(item) {
      return  $scope.filterParams.indexOf(item) !== -1;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are returning on the first iteration. You could do this instead:

```
$scope.myFilter = function(item) {
    return $scope.filterParams.indexOf(item) > -1;
};
```